# Implementing RNN/LSTMs on segmented inputs

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am designing a deep learning model for classifying inputs of length *m<sup>2</sup>*, and have the following multilayer LSTM model in mind:

Image (insufficient rep to post images): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijq68.png

Notice the LSTMs are m<sup>2</sup>-to-m<sup>2</sup> and m<sup>2</sup>-to-one respectively. However, *m<sup>2</sup>* is large, leaving the LSTMs susceptible to gradient vanishing/exploding. I thought of splitting the input into segments of size *m*, allowing the LSTMs to be m-to-one instead of m<sup>2</sup>-to-one:

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vhe8.png

- How do you implement this in, say, Tensorflow or Keras? I cannot find any documentation of LSTMs accepting multiple segments per input sample.
- Is there a better model than the one I proposed, for processing long sequential inputs that can be segmented?

Comment: In principle, it should be enough to reshape your `[m^2]` input into `[m, m]`, which you can do even beforehand in numpy  or whatever. I cannot help you with TF implementation of the rest, but I'm sure it could be easily done in PyTorch :-) Depending on the nature of your input, it might be worth using some 2d-convolutional architecture though. Or at least some average pooling over all the LSTM outputs, otherwise you discriminate against the elements you start the processing with.

Comment: @dedObed Thanks for the comment! The way I phrased the question was misleading; my data is actually sequential 1D data. My concern with 2D convolution is that it arbitrarily introduces proximity along the vertical axis which doesn't exist in my domain.

Answer (score 0):

- **How do you implement this in, say, Tensorflow or Keras?**
  By a repeated resphaping. Lets assume that your data is organized as `[B, m^2]`. So you reshape as you suggested to `[B, m, m ]`. Then you pretend that your batch does not consist of `B` samples, but `B*m` segments, by reshaping to `[B*m, m, 1]`, making the `1` explicit, because most RNN implementations I've seen (TF/Keras including) require explicit features per timestep. You run this through the LSTM and get `[B*m, k]`, where `k` is the width of the LSTM. Now you reshape back to `[B, m, k]` and you can run this through another LSTM, receiving `[B, j]`, where `j` is the width of this second LSTM. Then you can `Dense()` and `sigmoid` to get your binary classification, or whatever is the task.
- **Is there a better model than the one I proposed, for processing long sequential inputs that can be segmented?** Only you know your data, only you can decide. But from my point of view, what you propose is (1) already non-trivial. Better start with trivial baseline to get an idea of what you can expect. And (2), your proposal introduces breaks of the data at multiplies of `m`. Only you know the data, but this IMHO artificially limits the amount of patterns that your first LSTM can possibly mine from the data.

If it was my problem (and now I'm really marginalizing out any data-related thinking), I'd go as:

1. **An LSTM.** Will suffer from vanishing gradients, sure, but explosions can be mitigated by gradient clipping. It's super easy, can be applied on-line.
2. **A bi-LSTM.** You sacrifice the on-line processing to get much better representation, esp. of the initial part of the sequence. Should help both your model to become more accurate and you to get a better insight into what is (not) important for the task.
3. **Add mean pooling.** By mean-pooling over the outputs of LSTM (instead of just taking the last one), you effectively provide the target information to every time-step, which should again help to mine useful patterns, this time from somewhere in the middle, those poor gyus that didn't make through either forward or backward LSTM.
4. **1-d convolution.** Once you have the mean pooling in place, you can technically replace the LSTM by any local architecture, e.g. 1-d CNN. This or may not help, depending on your data and span of useful information in there. Anyway, CNNs are usually a bit easier to train a you get very nice parallelization properties, so a huge speedup during both train and test phase.